# nginx ignore location part

Tags: configuration, nginx, alias

I have spent an hour looking for an answer to this, but unless you know the vocabulary it is very difficult to search. What I want is dead simple. I have a server like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.dev;
  root /srv/www;

  location / {
    index foo.html;
  }

  location /foo {
    index foo.html;
  }

  location /bar {
    index foo.html;
  }
}
```

What I want is for /, /foo, and /bar to all point to the *exact same file*. In other words, I want the location part to be completely ignored. Just serve the file from the root directory that I tell you to serve.

Alias doesn't seem to be the answer, doesn't know which file it is supposed to serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use rewrite.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.dev;
  root /srv/www;

  location / {
  index foo.html;
  rewrite  ^/foo(.*)$ /$1  last;
  rewrite  ^/bar(.*)$ /$1  last;
  break;
  }

}
```

Something like that yah, I think you can figure it out from here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting each qualifying location to a named location which will serve the file.

```
server {
    ...
  error_page 418 = @response;

  location /foo {
    return 418;
  }
  location /bar {
    return 418;
  }
  location @response {
    index response.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although I fully believe this will work, I am very uncomfortable with returning an error code when this is not an error.

Comment: I understand that by default nginx interprets the location to be part of the filesystem path, but there must be a way to overwrite this behavior...